# Searching for children in wpf Grid in a different way

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a wpf grid which columns and rows are dynamically set from code-behind (user can change number of columns and rows).

If I use foreach loop to locate children objects in a grid (cell) it searches from "top to bottom" meaning from cell in col=0 row=0 then col=0 row=1 and so on... What I want is to search from "left to right" ie row=0 col=0 then row=0 col=1 and so on...

Order in which I add children elements in a List<> is very important.

I know I can do it with two nested for loops but is there more elegant (faster) way to do this?

(Cell is a UserControl)

```
List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();
foreach (Cell c in mainGrid.Children)
{
  cells.Add(c);
}

//...

for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
    {
        Cell cell = (Cell)mainGrid.Children.Cast<UIElement>()
                          .First(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == i && Grid.GetColumn(c) == j);
        cells.Add(cell);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use foreach loop to locate children objects in a grid (cell) it searches from "top to bottom"

That's actually not true. It simply returns the children in the order you added them to the Grid's Children collection, which has no relation to their location in the Grid. The reason you happen to get them in that order is because they were added to the Grid in that order.

If you want a more "elegant" way to do this (though probably not much faster), you can use linq's `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` with the attached `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties.

```
List<Cell> cells = mainGrid.Children
    .OfType<Cell>()
    .OrderBy(Grid.GetRow)
    .ThenBy(Grid.GetColumn)
    .ToList();
```

This solution is also a bit robust than your example in that it won't fail if there is a grid row or column that doesn't have a cell.

Comment: Whereas a quick access is important, you may create a couple of indexes (rows and columns) during the insertion, or when the grid children collection is stable.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I have no clue what your comment means

Comment: The comment was directed to the user posting the question, not you. I added it here, because it seems useful to complete your answer with something more. My consideration is about extracting the children quickly: your snippet offers kinda "query" against the collection. However, if you wish to quick access the children of a certain row, without scanning them all first, you could organize them in a dictionary or so. That should happen during the insertion, so the retrieval will be always very fast.